# All three word combinations (in the same order) from a string

Tags: php, cpu-word, permutation

Let's say we have a string with words:
1 2 3 4 5

I want all combinations of three words, but the order can't change. The string can be anywhere from 4 words up to 7 words long. Not longer as there would be too many combinations. So the result for the example 1 2 3 4 5 would be an array with strings:
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 4 5
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 4 5
3 4 5

I've been thinking about this for a while. One idea was to turn it into an array, generate a binary code for the amount of words and if it is a 1 then it shows the word and otherwise it doesn't (so you get anything from 11100 to 00111). But that's probably not optimal.

Speed matters in this case, as it possible has to be done tens of thousands of times within a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Vicky's answer and did some modifications.
I think this will work as you want

```
function everyCombination($array) {
    $tempcount = 3;                            //lenght of the combinations you want
    $arrayCount      = count($array);
    $maxCombinations = pow($arrayCount, $arrayCount);
    $returnArray     = array();
    $conversionArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $conversionArray[base_convert($key, 10, $arrayCount)] = $value;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $maxCombinations; $i++) {
        $flag = 1;
        $combination = base_convert($i, 10, $arrayCount);
        $combination = str_pad($combination, $tempcount, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $temp = strtr($combination, $conversionArray);
        for($j = 0; $j < $tempcount-1; $j++){

            if($temp[$j] >= $temp[$j+1] || $flag == 0)
                $flag = 0;
            else
                $flag = 1;
        }
        if($flag && strlen($temp) == $tempcount)
            $returnArray[] = $temp;
    }
    return $returnArray;
}

print_r(everyCombination(array(1,2,3,4)));
```

Comment: Awesome! I looked at Vicky's answer as well, but I couldn't figure out how to adjust it to make it work. This solution works. Thanks Vicky for the initial setup and Bhavik for the final solution!

Comment: Nooo...it doesn't work! :( It only works with numbers. I posted numbers in the example, because that made it more clear. But I was talking about WORDS in a string...

Comment: but what kind of words does that mean, only english alphabets? I can adjust the function accordingly. i have tried `everyCombination(array('a','b','c','d','e'))` and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as:

```
<?php
function everyCombination($array)
{
    $arrayCount = count($array);
    $resultArray = array();
    $veryFinal = array();
    $maxCombinations = pow($arrayCount, $arrayCount);
    $returnArray = array();
    $conversionArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $conversionArray[base_convert($key, 10, $arrayCount)] = $value;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $maxCombinations; $i++) {
        $combination = base_convert($i, 10, $arrayCount);
        $combination = str_pad($combination, $arrayCount, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $returnArray[] = strtr($combination, $conversionArray);
    }
    $finalArray = array();
    foreach ($returnArray as $sepArray) {
        array_push($finalArray, array_unique(str_split($sepArray)));
    }
    foreach ($finalArray as $result) {
        $temp = implode(",", $result);
        if (count($result) == 3) {
            array_push($resultArray, $temp);
        }
    }
    $tempFinal = array_unique($resultArray);
    foreach ($tempFinal as $final) {
        array_push($veryFinal, $final);
    }
    return $veryFinal;
}


$res1 = (everyCombination(array(1, 2, 3, 4)));
$res2 = (everyCombination(array('a','b','c','d')));
var_dump($res1);
var_dump($res2);
```

It Gives:

```
array (size=24)
  0 => string '1,2,3' (length=5)
  1 => string '1,2,4' (length=5)
  2 => string '1,3,2' (length=5)
  3 => string '1,3,4' (length=5)
  4 => string '1,4,2' (length=5)
  5 => string '1,4,3' (length=5)
  6 => string '2,1,3' (length=5)
  7 => string '2,1,4' (length=5)
  8 => string '2,3,1' (length=5)
  9 => string '2,3,4' (length=5)
  10 => string '2,4,1' (length=5)
  11 => string '2,4,3' (length=5)
  12 => string '3,1,2' (length=5)
  13 => string '3,1,4' (length=5)
  14 => string '3,2,1' (length=5)
  15 => string '3,2,4' (length=5)
  16 => string '3,4,1' (length=5)
  17 => string '3,4,2' (length=5)
  18 => string '4,1,2' (length=5)
  19 => string '4,1,3' (length=5)
  20 => string '4,2,1' (length=5)
  21 => string '4,2,3' (length=5)
  22 => string '4,3,1' (length=5)
  23 => string '4,3,2' (length=5)
array (size=24)
  0 => string 'a,b,c' (length=5)
  1 => string 'a,b,d' (length=5)
  2 => string 'a,c,b' (length=5)
  3 => string 'a,c,d' (length=5)
  4 => string 'a,d,b' (length=5)
  5 => string 'a,d,c' (length=5)
  6 => string 'b,a,c' (length=5)
  7 => string 'b,a,d' (length=5)
  8 => string 'b,c,a' (length=5)
  9 => string 'b,c,d' (length=5)
  10 => string 'b,d,a' (length=5)
  11 => string 'b,d,c' (length=5)
  12 => string 'c,a,b' (length=5)
  13 => string 'c,a,d' (length=5)
  14 => string 'c,b,a' (length=5)
  15 => string 'c,b,d' (length=5)
  16 => string 'c,d,a' (length=5)
  17 => string 'c,d,b' (length=5)
  18 => string 'd,a,b' (length=5)
  19 => string 'd,a,c' (length=5)
  20 => string 'd,b,a' (length=5)
  21 => string 'd,b,c' (length=5)
  22 => string 'd,c,a' (length=5)
  23 => string 'd,c,b' (length=5)
```

Comment: This solution changes the order of 1,2,3 which it shouldn't. For example it outputs 311. But that's not a combination which it should return (see initial request). Thanks for your time however.